# How to get some records without cursor, without Cross Apply in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called `Objects` which contains some files, say:

1. User
2. Teacher

There is another table (`States`) which holds the possible states of these objects, like:

1. Active
2. Idle
3. Teaching
4. Resting
5. Authoring

And there is a third table (junction table) which logs each state change of each object. In this third table (`ObjectStates`) records are like:

1. 1, 1, DateTime1 (User was active on DateTime1)
2. 2, 5, DateTime2 (Teacher was authoring on DateTime2)

etc.

Now, what I want is a query to get each object, with its latest state (not state history). It's possible to get this result using `cursors`, or using `Cross Apply` command. However, I'd like to know if there is any other way to get the latest states of each object from these three tables? Because `cursors` are costy.

Comment: A common pattern here is to have an active flag in the `ObjectStates` table and only have that flag on the latest record.

Comment: Also, since the state of an object might be a more common thing to query than the state change history, I would keep the current state at the object level for performance reasons.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? *(Are you refusing to use `CROSS APPLY` because you're on SQL Server 2000 or something? Another option is to use `ROW_NUMBER()`, but that is also not available in SQL Server 2000.)*

Comment: @MehdiEmrani - Then why are you refusing to use `APPLY`? The answers here are good, but so is `OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM x WHERE blah ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS ActiveState`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `row_number()` windowing function...

```
select * 
from
(

select objects.*,
       state.state,
       objectstates.changedate,
       row_number() over (partition by object.objectid order by changedate desc) rn
from 
    objects
         inner join
    objectstates
         on objects.id = objectstates.objectid
         inner join
    states 
         on objectstates.stateid = states.stateid
) v
where rn = 1
```

If you can't use `row_number` because you're on SQL 2000, for example, you can use a join on a `max/group by` query.

```
select objects.*,
       state.state,
       objectstates.changedate,
from 
    objects
         inner join
    objectstates
         on objects.id = objectstates.objectid
         inner join
    states 
         on objectstates.stateid = states.stateid
    inner join
         (select objectid, max(changedate) as maxdate from objectstates group by objectid) maxstates
         on objectstates.objectid=maxstates.objectid
         and objectstates.changedate = maxstates.maxdate
```

Answer (score 3):

You can join on the `ObjectStates` table twice. The first join of the table will get the `max(activedate)` for each `objectid`.  The second time, you will join on both the `objectid` and the value of the `max(activedate)` and this will get the `state` associated with that value:

```
select o.name o_name,
  s.name s_name,
  os1.activedate
from objects o
left join
(
  select max(activeDate) activedate, objectid
  from objectstates
  group by objectid
) os1
  on o.id = os1.objectid
left join ObjectStates os2
  on os1.objectid = os2. objectid
  and os1.activedate = os2.activedate
left join states s
  on os2.stateid = s.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96691/3)

Comment: Not perfect. When two things can happen on the same day. But given the right data and eliminating that possibility, will run faster than what I had.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi - There is an argument to say that if two changes are timestamped with the exact same value, the state is indeterminate. In that case there is an argument to return all possible values rather than a single arbitrary value. Whether the arguments are valid depends on the business case. My point being that `Not Perfect` could be equally applied to this answer and to all the other answers, and is a reflection of the data and the functional requirement not having a `perfect` match.

Comment: @Dems Can't agree. `Latest` implies a "MAX" type connotation, which reads as one and only one value. In the context of the question, that expands to one row, or TOP(1) along an order. If there can be duplicates, that's where the MAX form breaks down because you now have to do two levels to tie-break (without row_number()) and return the unique id along the tie-break order.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi while I agree that this could cause for multiple records on the same day (if time is not included in the datetime), the OP would need to provide some indication as to what status should be taken in the event there are two statuses for the same day. They did not include these details to be able to drill down further.

Comment: @bluefeet Every answer's got a downvote. Can't see a reason for any of them.

Comment: @podiluska ridiculous considering they are all valid

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi - If the schema allows multiple records with exactly the same timestamp, all such records have an equal claim to being the latest record. None in that group can claim to be later than any of the others. If the functional requirement requires a single record, but the schema allows multiple records, the requirement and the DDL don't match. Which is more right, to select one arbitrarily (and possibly a different one every time) or to select them all? I contend that neither is correct, for the scenario described the *functional requirement* is inadequate *(Not Perfect)*.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi I am not reading that as a singular.  "latest state (not state history)"  "get the latest states of each object"  So the first state was not plural.  Not state history to me is remove prior but keep current.  The second reference is plural.

Answer (score -1):

In the good old days, we just used Scalar subqueries.

```
select o.*, (select top(1) s.description
               from objectstates os
               join states s on s.id = os.state_id
              where os.object_id = o.id
           order by os.recorded_time desc) last_state 
  from objects o;
```

Which CROSS APPLY replaces.  To extend it to more fields, it had to be extended something like

```
select *
  from (
select o.*, (select top(1) os.id
               from objectstates os
              where os.object_id = o.id
           order by os.recorded_time desc) last_state 
  from objects o
       ) x
   join objectstates os on os.id = x.last_state
   join states s on s.id = os.state_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use partition over to find the latest row for each Object, like this

```
create table #ObjectState
(
    Object int NOT NULL,
    State int NOT NULL,
    TimeStamp datetime NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #ObjectState (Object, State, TimeStamp) VALUES (1, 1, '2012-01-01')
INSERT INTO #ObjectState (Object, State, TimeStamp) VALUES (1, 2, '2012-01-02')
INSERT INTO #ObjectState (Object, State, TimeStamp) VALUES (1, 3, '2012-01-03')
INSERT INTO #ObjectState (Object, State, TimeStamp) VALUES (2, 4, '2012-01-01')
INSERT INTO #ObjectState (Object, State, TimeStamp) VALUES (2, 2, '2012-01-02')

select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Object order by TimeStamp desc) as RowNo from #ObjectState

select InnerSelect.Object, InnerSelect.State, InnerSelect.TimeStamp FROM
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Object order by TimeStamp desc) as RowNo from #ObjectState
) InnerSelect
where InnerSelect.RowNo = 1


DROP TABLE #ObjectState
```

gives output

```
Object  State  TimeStamp
1       3      2012-01-03 00:00:00.000
2       2      2012-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

for the last select